# What is the difference between on_data and on_status in the tweepy library?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I just started using `tweepy` library to connect with streaming api of twitter. I encountered both `on_status()` and `on_data()` methods of the `StreamListener` class. What is the difference? Total noob here!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`on_data()` handles:

- replies to statuses
- deletes
- events
- direct messages
- friends
- limits, disconnects and warnings

whereas, `on_status()` just handles statuses.

source: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/78d2883a922fa5232e8cdfab0c272c24b8ce37c4/tweepy/streaming.py

Comment: help me out here. Say, I wanted to print all tweets(filtered by a specific keyword) in the past 5 minutes, what should I do?

Answer (score 4):

If you're only concerned with tweets, use `on_status()`. This will give you what you needed without the added information and doing so will not hinder your limit.

If you want detailed information use `on_data()`. --That's rarely the case unless you're doing heavy analysis.