# Python twitter stream save to file

Tags: python, twitter, save, streaming

Im current working on a code to stream twitter posts and save them to a json file. Simultaneously, textblob determines the sentiment of a tweet. 
Everything is working so far but not saving all the output to a file. It currently saves the tweets but it doesn't save the sentiment score calculated by textblob. This is my first day coding in Python and I appreciate every bit of help :)

```
import textblob as textblob
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import json
from textblob import TextBlob

# consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret.
consumer_key = x
consumer_secret = x
access_token = x
access_token_secret = x


class StdOutlistener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        all_data = json.loads(data)
        tweet = TextBlob(all_data["text"])
        print(tweet)
        print(tweet.sentiment)

        # Open json text file to save the tweets
        With open('tweets.json', 'a') as tf:
            tf.write(data)

        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)


auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, StdOutlistener())
twitterStream.filter(languages=["en"], track=["Test"])
```

Comment: Exactly what is your question?

Comment: O i see i was a bit unclear: 1: I would like to combine tweets with the sentiment. 2: I would like to know how i can write the tweets and sentiment to a json file. Jake made some assumptions and they were correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First are you sure you want to be using `on_data` rather than `on_status`, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054656/what-is-the-difference-between-on-data-and-on-status-in-the-tweepy-library) details the difference between the two. I'm not too familiar with `tweepy` so may be wrong on this count.

Second you don't appear to be correctly updating the data regarding the sentiment. You calculate it with `tweet = TextBlob(all_data['text'])`, but then don't do anything further with the `tweet` variable or `all_data` variable. What you want would be something like `all_data['sentiment'] = tweet.sentiment`.

Finally you aren't correctly writing the data to your file at the end. I'm working off the assumption that you want the file to be a collection of JSON entries rather than a single JSON document. What you are doing is writing the provided string `data` to the end of the file, with no new line, rather than any updated dictionary you might have. You would instead want to write the `all_data` dictionary to file as a JSON object.

An example fix of my above points would be:

```
import textblob as textblob
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import json
from textblob import TextBlob

# consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret.
consumer_key = x
consumer_secret = x
access_token = x
access_token_secret = x


class StdOutlistener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        all_data = json.loads(data)
        tweet = TextBlob(all_data["text"])

        #Add the 'sentiment data to all_data
        all_data['sentiment'] = tweet.sentiment

        print(tweet)
        print(tweet.sentiment)

        # Open json text file to save the tweets
        With open('tweets.json', 'a') as tf:
            # Write a new line
            tf.write('\n')

            # Write the json data directly to the file
            json.dump(all_data, tf)
            # Alternatively: tf.write(json.dumps(all_data))

        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)


auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, StdOutlistener())
twitterStream.filter(languages=["en"], track=["Test"])
```

Comment: Hi Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for and super explanation. Regarding the json data; i didn't know writing a new line is necessary. But your assumptions were right; i don't want a single json document

Comment: It's simply that python doesn't automatically write a new line when you are appending. If the new line was written, then you would simply have a over line fine like `{<tweet_data>}{<other_tweet_data>}...`. Another solution would be to always ensure your write a new line character at the end of your data, which would get basically the same result.